# How can I declare a pointer based on a generic type?

Tags: delphi, generics, pointers, parameters, delphi-2010

I have a class like this:

```
type A = class
    procedure<T> DoStuff(tPtr: ^T);
end;
```

But when I try to compile, Delphi gives me this error:

```
[DCC Error] RPML.pas(57): E2029 Identifier expected but '^' found
```

How can I use a pointer to a parameterized type in a Delphi procedure? I don't want to make the whole class a template class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To do this you need to declare a pointer type as a nested type in the generic class:

```
type 
  TMyGeneric<T> = class
  type
    P = ^T;
  public
    procedure DoStuff(tPtr: P);
  end;
```

And if you want a class method (i.e. not an instance method) you can do it this way:

```
type
  TMyGeneric<T> = record
  type
    P = ^T;
  public
    class procedure DoStuff(tPtr: P); static;
  end;

var
  int: Integer;
...
TMyGeneric<Integer>.DoStuff(@int);
```

Or using a var parameter:

```
type
  TMyGeneric<T> = record
  public
    class procedure DoStuff(var a: T); static;
  end;
```

It seems to be common to use records rather than classes for generic types that don't ever get instantiated.

<strike>Finally, you cannot have, in Delphi, a generic method without making the class generic. In other words there is no analogue of the following C++ template code:</strike>

Thorsten's answer shows how to implement a generic method without making the class generic, that is the Delphi analogue of of the following C++ template code:

```
class C {
public:
   template <typename T>
   int SomeTemplateFunction(T* data) {
      printf("Address of parameter is %p\n", data);
      return 0;
   }
};

int a; 
char c; 
C cinst; 
cinst.SomeTemplateFunction<int>(&a); 
cinst.SomeTemplateFunction<char>(&c);
```

Thorsten's answer gives you a class function but in the comments you state you are looking for a normal member function.

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  public
    procedure DoStuff<T>(var a: T);
  end;

procedure TMyClass.DoStuff<T>(var a: T);
begin
end;

...
var
  instance: TMyClass;
  i: Integer;
  s: string;
...
  instance.DoStuff<Integer>(i);
  instance.DoStuff<string>(s);
```

However, what I'm struggling with is how exactly you could do anything very useful with this, in Delphi, that could not be done just as effectively without a generic solution.

I'd appreciate any suggestions and would be happy to edit the answer to accommodate them.

Comment: @David: Are you sure that's the only way? The only reason I made the function a class function is so I could use generics, and I don't want to make the user of the class create a new instance of the class for every different type he wants to use the function with. In fact, a requirement is that the user can use the same function with different type parameters on the same instance of a class. If this is really the only way, it's a mindblowing limitation of Delphi.

Comment: @David I have another instance of this problem where it can't be a class method. Please answer my question in the above comment.

Comment: @Hal I have answered it. You would never have an instance of the generic type in the second code section of the updated answer. You just call it `MyGeneric<Integer>.DoStuff(@int);` It's a bit wordy, but that's just how you do it.

Comment: @David No, you misread. I said:  In fact, a requirement is that the user can use the same function with different type parameters on the same instance of a class. This means that they must be able to do `mg.DoStuff<Integer>(@int); mg.DoStuff<PAnsiChar>(@pac);`

Comment: @Hal You can't do that with generics and I don't even think you can do that with C++ templates. I don't really believe it's a "mindblowing limitation of Delphi".

Comment: @David of course you can do it with C++ templates, it's been available for as long as I can remember. This handicap will make the class I am converting a pain to use. It may not seem like a limitation to you because you've never had to use it. Another feature Delphi lacks is letting normal (non-method) functions have parameterized types, but that's another story.

Comment: @Hal "Another feature Delphi lacks is letting normal (non-method) functions have parameterized types". No, you do that with class methods on records.

Comment: "class methods on records" My point exactly, it makes using this feature more cumbersome for no benefit.

Comment: @Hal I've not been able to find an example of this C++ template feature. Could you point me to one?

Comment: @Hal "It makes using this feature more cumbersome for no benefit". That's just the way it is. No point complaining to me, I didn't invent it!

Comment: @David is passing a parameter as `var` exactly like passing it by reference in C++?

Comment: @Hal How do you instantiate C and how do you specialise the templated method?

Comment: @Hal Delphi var param is equivalent to C++ reference param.

Comment: @Hal OK I see how to work that C++ class. It's pretty funky! I don't believe there's anything like that in Delphi generics. I also think that Java or .net generics do not have that level of generality. Or am I wrong there too?!!

Comment: @David ok, the `var` thing makes it slightly better. As to your question, you can do it like this: `int a; char c; C cinst; cinst.SomeTemplateFunction<int>(&a); cinst.SomeTemplateFunction<char>(&c);` Also forgive me but the code I pasted was slightly inaccurate. Here is the correct version (added `public` and added a return value to `SomeTemplateFunction`): http://codepad.org/VMitbMRq.

Comment: @David in response to your edited comment, I don't know about Java or .NET, I don't program in either of those. And while it is funky, it provides excellent flexibility and you can do things you couldn't do otherwise (or they would be extremely clunky).

Comment: @Hal I meant funky in a positive way. I'd already fixed your original version. My Delphi codebase has areas that perform numerical algorithms that would work on both real and complex (for examples) data types. But I can't abstract the code because Delphi doesn't have templates. It's a weakness and a limitation, but it's hardly mindblowing. I think C++ templates are pretty unique. What other language has the equivalent?

Comment: @David sorry but I have one more question, if you have a parameter like `var a: array of T` is `a` the base address of the array in memory? That is to say, can you cast a into a `Pointer` and operate on it like a pointer?

Comment: Oh and as for your question, I don't know, and it's probably foolish of me to expect Delphi to provide all the features C++ does (I don't expect C++ to provide all the features Delphi does), I just love C++ and am disappointed when I can't do exactly what I want with Delphi because I love Delphi too. This particular thing is rather important to me because I am doing some rather wierd things (calling functions in other processes) which require me to know the size of all parameters, etc. and it's difficult without C++'s level of flexibility.

Comment: @Hal You can probably do some dirty pointer hackery with Delphi open arrays, but I must say I have never done so. I'd expect there to be a hack-free solution to your problem.

Comment: @Hal I think that more flexible generic/algorithmic programming is the main  C++ feature that I miss in Delphi.

Comment: @Hal By the way, I've updated my answer, I think it's comprehensive now. If you are satisfied with the answer then please accept it by clicking the tick near the top of the answer.

Comment: @Hal Your question about open arrays is probably worth a separate question, with some background to explain what and why. Buried down here in the comments it might go un-noticed. As a new question you'll probably generate a few answers.

Comment: @David ok, I'll make a new question of it.

Comment: @Hal, the elements of an array are always contiguous. The address of the array's storage block is always the same as the address of the array's first element. Although the syntax for the address of the array can vary based on the kind of array you have, the syntax for getting the address of the first element is always the same, whether it's an open array, a dynamic array, or a static array: `@a[Low(a)]`.

Answer (score 5):

You can move the generic parameter from the class to the method, and use var instead of a pointer type:

```
type
  TMyGeneric = record
    class procedure DoStuff<T>(var aParam: T); static;
  end;

var
  int : Integer;
  s   : string;
...
TMyGeneric.DoStuff<Integer>(int);
TMyGeneric.DoStuff<string>(s);
```

EDIT: Unfortunately the Delphi compiler doesn't seem to be able to perform type inference when var parameters are used which makes it necessary to explicitly specify the generic paramter type using <..> on the method calls.

Without the "var" the <..> can be omitted (but then the method can no longer modify the passed in variable).

Comment: +1 Cool. I didn't know you could do this (evidently!) However, that doesn't compiler for me. I think you need: `TMyGeneric.DoStuff<Integer>(int)`.

Comment: You are right, with "var" you need to use <Integer>. I didn't have a reason to make use of type inference for var parameters before and made the mistake of assuming that it works just as well as it does with non-var parameters. Clearly the Delphi compiler is even more limited still with generics than I thought. The type inference works if you leave out the "var", but I assume that the Questioner asked about pointers because he intents to modify the passed in variable, so leaving out the var is not an option.

Comment: I think you should edit your example so it compiles, and correct the final paragraph.

Comment: I think everyone is realizing the Delphi compiler is even more limited with generics than they thought today. I also noticed that with generics (in RAD Studio 2010) Intellisense is very prone to screwing up and thinking that templatized methods do not exist, but it compiles fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
type
  Pointer<T> = record
  public type
    Ty = ^T;
  end;
```

Now you can use this generic pointer anywhere

```
type A = class
    procedure<T> DoStuff(tPtr: Pointer<T>.Ty);
end;
```